# Java: PostgreSQL: Spring Boot: could not execute native query with interval and limit

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, intervals

I'm working on the migration from **MySql** to **PostgreSQL**. So, I'm actualizing the **Spring Data** queries in repositories. And I've faced with the problem with the following **native** query:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE some_table SET some_field= :someValue, changed_at=now() WHERE (changed_at < now() - INTERVAL :timeout MINUTE) LIMIT :limit", nativeQuery = true)
int updateRecords(@Param("someValue") String someValue, @Param("timeout") int timeoutMinutes, @Param("limit") int limit);
```

It works fine with the MySql, but with the PostgeSQL the fllowing error occurs:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the length of the interval in that way.

It's easier to use `make_interval()` instead:

```
changed_at < now() - make_interval(mins => :timeout)
```

Or, if JPA also chokes on the `=>`

```
changed_at < now() - (interval '1 minute' * :timeout)
```

Comment: Your first query works fine. Thanks! As for `You can't pass the "size" of the interval in that way.` - but it works with the MySQL! Don't understand how...

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili. MySQL uses a non-standard syntax for intervals to begin with. `interval 1 minute` is invalid standard SQL and invalid in Postgres. According to the SQL standard (which Postgres follows) the interval "length" is passed as a string constant - but one that can't be a parameter (it's similar to an identifier)

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili: btw: the make_interval() function is non-standard where as the second expression would be standard SQL (if it weren't for the non-standard `now()` which could be replaced with `current_timstamp`)